# What Error Handling Code should I Use if VBA Macro tried to filter but filter was not found in the row

Tags: excel

I tried this code. and tried to filter "May", but in Sol_MSBI.xlsx, there is no "May", how do I handle this.

```
Sub refresh()

    Windows("Sol_MSBI.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_query").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1 _
        :="MAY"
    Windows("Sol_SceOtc.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_query").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1 _
        :="MAY"
End Sub
```

Comment: It won't cause an error in that code so why do you need to handle it?

Comment: You could search the column first for May, if found do the autofilter, else skip it.

Comment: This caused error:
Windows("Sol_MSBI.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_query").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1 _
        :="MAY"

because there is no May in the cell filtered. what code do I add to skip if "may" is not found ? (I'm no programmer, was just trying so simplify reports)

Comment: That will **not** cause an error just because MAY is not in the data. What was the error message?

Comment: Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range